# How to I obtain the Album picture of a music in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, mutagen

I am trying to insert the album pictutre of a music(mp3) as an image in Python GUI window. I used [mutagen](https://mutagen.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) ID3 picture class for this purpose. It was described in the [docs](https://mutagen.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/id3.html#mutagen.id3.PictureType) but I excactly dont know how to do it. So kindly I would like to request for an example to show how to do it correctly. And if possible, please specify if there is any alternative.

Thank-you!

Comment: There is an alternative library - [stagger](https://github.com/lorentey/stagger), which is pretty much easier to use than mutagen(really; you can do stuff like `mp3.artist = 'Artist'`). If you want to use mutagen, you should use the `APIC` frame(if you want to know how to do this with stagger, please let me know).

Comment: @Gokul Thanks Gokul ! Yes, I am interested  to learn more on  "stagger". Can you give some simple examples? Or is there any tutorial.....Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Stagger](https://github.com/lorentey/stagger) is a library for modifying id3v2 tags; it's pretty much easy to use:

```
In [1]: import stagger

In [2]: mp3 = stagger.read_tag('/home/gokul/Music/Linkin Park - Burning In The Skies.mp3')

In [3]: mp3.artist
Out[3]: 'Linkin Park'

In [4]: mp3.album
Out[4]: 'A Thousand Suns'

In [5]: mp3.picture  # the cover has not been set yet
Out[5]: ''
```

Rest of the API is similar to this. You can modify tags like this:

```
In [6]: mp3.album = 'Changed It'

In [7]: mp3.album
Out[7]: 'Changed It'
```

To set the album/cover picture, all you have to do is....

```
In [10]: mp3.picture = '/home/gokul/Pictures/Cover.jpg' # path to file

In [11]: mp3.picture  # the cover has been saved!
Out[11]: 'Other(0)::<2834 bytes of jpeg data>'
```

You have to save the tags to the file now:

```
In [12]: mp3.write()
```

That's it! Done ;)
If you want to see all the tags in the file use `mp3.frames`:

```
In [13]: mp3.frames()
Out[13]: 
[TIT2(encoding=0, text=['Burning In The Skies']),
TPE1(encoding=0, text=['Linkin Park']),
TALB(encoding=0, text=['Changed It']),
APIC(encoding=None, mime='image/jpeg', type=0, desc='', data=<2834 bytes of binary data b'\xff\xd8\xff\xe0\x00\x10JFIF\x00\x01\x01\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00'...>)]
```

Cheers!

P.S. You can modify any id3v2 tag using stagger; some of them(most common) can be modified using a format like `mp3.title = 'title'`. See [stagger's GitHub page](https://github.com/lorentey/stagger) for editing other(uncommon and complex) tags.

Comment: Thank you Gokul! Its lot more easier than Mutagen. But there's  a  problem. How can I put the image in a GUI? I am getting only a code 'Other(0)::<16937 bytes of jpeg data>' instead of an image. Anyways Thanks Again!!

Comment: You're welcome :) You can do that by: `mp3[stagger.id3.APIC][0].data`. You will get the binary data.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Now I am able to get the whole data of the image :D But when I tried to put the Image on a GUI, I faced unicode error......[UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte]  I think for decoding it to bytes but is there any proper way for decoding the data of Image?  Thanks Gokul for spending your precious time for me. Thank you!!

Comment: I don't think there is; I'm not at all sure :|

Comment: Its OK. Anyways Thank you so much Gokul for helping me a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

I started from Gokul's answer and found out that there is a way to decode the image data that you get with stagger with the following code:

```
from PIL import Image
import stagger
import io

mp3 = stagger.read_tag('song.mp3')
by_data = mp3[stagger.id3.APIC][0].data
im = io.BytesIO(by_data)
imageFile = Image.open(im)
```

The imageFile variable holds the image in the same way as if you imported a jpg directly with

```
imageFile = Image.open("test_image.jpg")
```

So now you can use the album art from the mp3 file however you want. I think there are multiple ways to add an image to a GUI, but the method I use is to add the lines

```
import tkinter
from PIL import ImageTk

photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(imageFile)
label = tkinter.Label(image=photo)
label.image = photo
label.pack()
```